# Javascript - Want to concatenate embedded expressions to the <div> id

Tags: javascript, templates, expression, literals

Following is my code to help -

```
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     catBoxes.innerHTML += `
     <label>Select ${i+1} Category</label>
     <select id="box-category" class="custom-select" name="">
        ${categories.map((i) => {
            return "<option value='"+i['id']+"'>"+i['name']+"</option>"
        }).join("")};
     </select>         
     `;                                      
 }
```

This above code is working fine, what i want to change in this code is the following -

```
<select id="box-category"${i} class="custom-select" name="">
```

But i is not concatenating after the id.
Final output is supposed to be

```
<select id="box-category1" class="custom-select" name="">
<select id="box-category2" class="custom-select" name="">
```

and so on..

Your help is much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: `<select id="box-category"${i} class="custom-select" name="">` looks like a typo. I think you mean `<select id="box-category${i}" class="custom-select" name="">` (the substitution should be **within** the quoted attribute value).

Comment: Side note: Don't use `+=` with `innerHTML`. It makes the browser go through the contents of the element building up an HTML string, pass that string to the JavaScript code, get the updated string back from the JavaScript code, destroy the contents of the element, and then parse the new string into new elements. (Losing any element state, event handlers, etc., along the way.) Instead, use `catBoxes.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", yourHTML)` to just append.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Bravo! worked on the first go. Also thanks for the innerHTML clarification.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Since the size variable is also dynamic and coming as a dropdown value. So as the size value changes only that many select tags will be appended to catBoxes. So I think i have to use `catBoxes.innerHTML = "";` anyway right before the for loop to clear off anything that's present beforehand.

Comment: Your original code didn't do that either. But yes, if you need to clear it, I'd suggest building up all the HTML in a local variable, then doing `catBoxes.innerHTML = theHTML` once at the end after the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a typo, I need to move the embedded expression `${i}` inside quotes.

```
<select id="box-category"${i} class="custom-select" name="">

<select id="box-category${i}" class="custom-select" name="">
```

Also as explained by @T.J.Crowder
Don't use += with innerHTML. It makes the browser go through the contents of the element building up an HTML string, pass that string to the JavaScript code, get the updated string back from the JavaScript code, destroy the contents of the element, and then parse the new string into new elements. (Losing any element state, event handlers, etc., along the way.) Instead, use catBoxes.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", yourHTML) to just append.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
<select id="box-category"${i} class="custom-select" name="">
```

to

```
<select id="box-category${i}" class="custom-select" name="">
```